# Duplicate same dependency in package.json devDependencies and peerDependencies?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, react-dom

I'm currently building React UI component package that will be published to NPM.

I added React and ReactDOM to peer dependencies as it should be. However inside my library I have dependencies on modules like `react-dates` that also have React as peer.

And when I do `npm i` inside my package I got a lot of warnings like this that pollute my terminal:

```
warning " > react-dates@21.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14 || ^15.5.4 || ^16.1.1".
warning " > react-dates@21.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14 || ^15.5.4 || ^16.1.1".
```

As a workaround I decided to also add React and ReactDOM to `devDependencies` and warnings disappeared.

Do you think it's a good approach to duplicate dependencies in `dev` and `peer`?

Comment: Yes, it's totally fine to have same deps in `dev` and `peer`. Your dev deps are local to your project and won't be downloaded/duped for your package users.